# Métodos mágicos do python em javascript

Tags: javascript, python

Os objetos em python tem alguns métodos mágicos como `__init__`, `__str__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__gt__`, `__lt__`, `__ge__` e `__le__`. Como simular esses métodos em javascript, pra quando eu fizer `console.log(obj)` escreva uma descrição personalizada do objeto?

Comment: Se você tiver um projeto em que queira usar vários desses métodos e tenha que rodar client-side, uma alternativa pode ser usar Python mesmo no navegador. O projeto Brython (http://brython.info) permite isso.

Answer (score 4):

O mais próximo que se aproxima do que desejas é o método `toString`:

```js
class Vector {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  toString() {
    return `Vector(${this.x}, ${this.y})`;
  }
}

const v = new Vector(1, 2);

console.log(v);
```

Porém, perceba que não funciona da forma desejada. Isso porque o método `toString` só é invocado quando o JavaScript tenta efetuar o *cast* do objeto para uma *string*. Como a função `console.log` aceita também um objeto, o método não é executado. Mas se você fizer a concatenação do objeto com uma *string* vazia, o *cast* ocorrerá e o resultado será o desejado:

```js
class Vector {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  toString() {
    return `Vector(${this.x}, ${this.y})`;
  }
}

const v = new Vector(1, 2);

console.log(v + '');
```

Outros métodos citados são métodos de sobrecarga de operadores e o JavaScript não possui suporte a isso.

Comment: O mesmo se aplica ao método `valueOf()`, porém com retorno numérico.